# Unable to read changes made in HTML attribute on client Side by Javascript to ASP.NET server side

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I'm trying to read a class that is added by `Javascript` on a click event, in `ASP.NET` server side code but it still shows only those class which were add by server while initialization.

Here's the sreenshot of HTML element.
[image]

Here is what ASP.NET code is reading.
[image]

I'v even tried reading it like 
`string css = imgThumbnail.Attrinutes["class"].ToString();` 
but it still returns the same.

I want to read that 'border-10' class on code behind.

Comment: You cannot. As @Heagon says, changes made to the UI with javascript do not get send to the server on PostBack, You need to send that data in a HiddenField for example.

Comment: Thanks for clearing my doubt and for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `HiddenFileds` or a hidden `TextBox` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, like Mahdi said, you need to use hidden fields. 
So make hidden field, Example:

```
<input type="hidden" id="Yourstylesheetinfo" asp-for="Yoursheetinfo" />
```

Then, set value to that field via JS:

```
 var YourElement = document.getElementById(`YourElementsID`);
 var style = window.getComputedStyle(YourElement);
 //if you looking for border
 var property = style.getPropertyValue('border');

 //Lastly set value to hidden input
 document.getElementById(`Yourstylesheetinfo`).value = property; 
 //maybe you'll need to use .toString() on property ? on line above this..
```

Something like this maybe.